# What are the WWF 3.0/3.5 things that I have to unlearn if I want to start with WWF 4.0?

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I know that Microsoft has completely redesigned workflow foundation. I guess, backward and forward compatibilities are also broken. With that, I want to know the things that are true for WWF 3.0/3.5 but does not hold true for WWF 4.0.

Comment: Check out Microsoft's WF 4 Migration Guidance at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8349

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is everything technical :-(

Basically WF4 is a completely new and redesigned product with no backward relation to WF3 other than the architectural problem it addresses. You will find some class names are the same but the way they work is completely different.